# discord.js Strange error with own coded music bot. On PC works, on V-Server not

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm currently coding a musicbot for discord with the goal to support nightbot from twitch. (YouTube, Soundcloud)
But I ran into a problem with playing sound.

I wrote everything and tested it on my pc.
It "works". My bot joined and played music. The quality of the music was bad, because my CPU and Internet-Connection.
So I send it to my V-Server, installed all requirements and run it.
He started normally and joined normally my channel, but it doesn't play any sound.

I tried different types of play music.

```
//const dispatcher = serverqueue.connection.playFile("./sound.mp3");
const dispatcher = serverqueue.connection.playStream(ytdl(song.url));
//const dispatcher = serverqueue.connection.playArbitraryInput("http://iedsoftworks.com/sound.mp3");
```

I think, that is the problem, but my entire code can you find 
[here](https://pastebin.com/mUrrrNeE).

And another problem is, I didn't get any error messages.

So, is someone ran in the same problem and can me tell how to fix it?

Comment: Does the YTDL version work on your PC, or just the MP3 versions? Can you add trace etc. to work out if the YTDL part works at least? I doubt it'll download you an MP3 file, except maybe in 'audioonly' mode, and even then it'd probably be the raw audio stream from the video which isn't likely to be MP3. Can you check what format that is? Does playStream definitely support it, and / or stripping the audio stream straight out of a video?

Comment: @Rup The YTDL version worked on my PC. And after I've uploaded (and it doesn't works) I tried the other methods, and they don't work.

Comment: Do you have FFmpeg installed on the V-server?

Comment: @slothiful Yes. Without it, I will get a error.